# How to retrieve image stored in cloudant database using map

Tags: dictionary, cloudant, nosql

By using this function i am able to retrieve all the string details

```
public static Task fromRevision(BasicDocumentRevision rev) {
    Task t = new Task();
    t.rev = rev;
    // this could also be done by a fancy object mapper
    Map<String, Object> map = rev.asMap();
    if(map.containsKey("type") && map.get("type").equals(Task.DOC_TYPE)) {
        t.setType((String) map.get("type"));
        t.setCompleted((Boolean) map.get("completed"));
        t.setDescription((String) map.get("description"));
       t.setName((String) map.get("name"));
        t.setPhone((String) map.get("phone"));
        t.setAddress((String) map.get("address"));
        t.setSubdescription((String) map.get("subdescription"));
        t.setPrice((String) map.get("price"));
        t.setLocation((String) map.get("location"));
        t.setArea((String) map.get("area"));
        t.setInfo((String) map.get("info"));
        t.setCity((String) map.get("city"));
        return t;
    }
    return null;
}
```

now i want to retrieve image stored as attachment.
What should I add to this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

To get at the attachment from the `BasicDocumentRevisions` you access the attachments map, where the attachment is **always** keyed by the **name** of the attachment, so all you need to do is:

```
Attachment attachment = rev.attachments.get("attachmentName");
```